# Adding a big data layer to google maps - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to add a lot of data to a google map (local 3MB+ kml file, will probably be more). I have tried using the KML-layer, but showing all these data seems to use a lot of processing power, so the application/map is getting laggy when scrolling around.

I tried splitting the KML file up into smaller files and loading them according to the camera's position, but I'm still having these performance issues. I also want to show most of the data when the users zoom level is low, so this is not an optimal solution anyway.

I have looked a bit into google fusion layers. Google fusion layers seems to have better performance but is only included in the javascript API for google maps.

Will GEO-JSon improve the performance significantly?

Do you have any tips in how I can encounter this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnkTi6DfVKk) contains how Geojson makes it easier when using google maps. It does not tell that Geojson may improve performance but it says in the video how powerful Geosjson is when combined with Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel i have to answer my own question here. I tried using Geo-Json instead of KML and it increased the performance significantly. Together with [Marker clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering) from the google utility library i now have a pretty good solution.

I experienced some problems with placing a lot of polylines to the map, and it caused the app to skip alot of frames, but by adding them one by one with 10ms delay it worked pretty good.